# UWP XamlBindingHelper.ConvertValue throws an AccessViolationException when converting Decimal Values

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I created a simple XAML form using MVVM Light using UWP Platform. Up until now, I've never had an issue with databinding, but after creating a few textboxes bound to decimal properties, it throws the following exception in the code generated view file.

> System.AccessViolationException occurred
>     HResult=0x80004003
>     Message=Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
>     Source=
>     StackTrace:

The error only occurs in case 12, but not in case 11.  The ConvertValue appears to be at fault.

```
                case 11: // Views\QuotesPage.xaml line 82
                    this.obj11 = (global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ToggleSwitch)target;
                    (this.obj11).RegisterPropertyChangedCallback(global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ToggleSwitch.IsOnProperty,
                        (global::Windows.UI.Xaml.DependencyObject sender, global::Windows.UI.Xaml.DependencyProperty prop) =>
                        {
                        if (this.initialized)
                        {
                            // Update Two Way binding
                            this.dataRoot.ViewModel.SignatureRequiredOnDelivery = this.obj11.IsOn;
                        }
                    });
                    break;
                case 12: // Views\QuotesPage.xaml line 85
                    this.obj12 = (global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBox)target;
                    (this.obj12).LostFocus += (global::System.Object sender, global::Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e) =>
                    {
                        if (this.initialized)
                        {
                            // Update Two Way binding
                            this.dataRoot.ViewModel.InsuredValue = (global::System.Decimal) global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlBindingHelper.ConvertValue(typeof(global::System.Decimal), this.obj12.Text);
                        }
                    };
                    break;
```

Here's my block of XAML:

```
                <TextBlock Text="Weight" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" />
            <TextBox Text="{x:Bind Mode=TwoWay, Path=ViewModel.Weight}" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="weight" />

            <TextBlock Text="Signature Required On Delivery" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" />
            <ToggleSwitch IsOn="{x:Bind Mode=TwoWay, Path=ViewModel.SignatureRequiredOnDelivery}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" x:Name="signatureRequiredOnDelivery" />

            <TextBlock Text="Insured Value" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" />
            <TextBox Text="{x:Bind Mode=TwoWay, Path=ViewModel.InsuredValue}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" x:Name="insuredValue" />

            <TextBlock Text="Is Oversize" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" />
            <ToggleSwitch IsOn="{x:Bind Mode=TwoWay, Path=ViewModel.IsOversize}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" x:Name="isOversize" Height="40" Width="154" />
```

Here's my view model:
        private bool _signatureRequiredOnDelivery;
        public bool SignatureRequiredOnDelivery
        {
            get => _signatureRequiredOnDelivery;
            set => Set(ref _signatureRequiredOnDelivery, value);
        }

```
    private decimal _insuredValue = decimal.Zero;
    public decimal InsuredValue
    {
        get => _insuredValue;
        set => Set(ref _insuredValue, value);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's by design. You could use float instead of using decimal as Matt Small has mentioned in this thread [WinRT XAML : Binding text to decimal causes](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b0bfe9b9-7634-40d2-8d81-c664498cae6a/winrt-xaml-binding-text-to-decimal-causes?forum=winappswithcsharp)

You also could create a IValueConverter to solve this issue like Darrel Miller mentioned in above thread.

Comment: Thanks. You mean it's a bug. I saw the thread.  I wasn'r able to find a bug report on it.  I was thinking of filing one, but gave up after wading through the labyrinth of dead ends. Years ago, a bug like this would have been noticed fairly quickly. It is concerning that less Windows development is going on these days. Microsoft screwed up badly.

Comment: @ATL_DEV This is by design. But you could submit your feedback in  windows feedback hub.

Comment: Xie,  What design principle are you using at MSFT?  What happened to meaningful exceptions?  Is .NET Core too memory restrictive to add at least a message like "decimals not supported?"  Do you realize throwing an inaccurate, if not wrong, AccessViolationException will lead a programmer to spend hours down a dead end?

Comment: Xie, Doesn't Microsoft have a proper and official place to file bug reports instead of a general feedback page or GitHub?  Feedback generally means a place where you submit suggestions and opinions, not technical issues.

Comment: @ATL_DEV Sorry for my unclear reply. I meant that you could submit this question in windows feedback hub, if it's a bug, you will be able to trace its status easily on your side. MS has internal channel to report, I could help you report it.